# Using context.drawImage() to draw a semi-transparent image over a none transparent image?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

At the moment i have 2 tiles that look like this:

[image]

And this:

[image]

I want to draw the blue, semi - transparent image over the fully opaque yellow image using ctx.drawImage, and have the result look something like this:

[image]

However instead of blending with the bottom tile, the ctx.drawImage() function just overwrites the pixels below the blue tile.

My code looks like this:

```
var c = document.getElementById("game");
//Properties of the canvas.

var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

var readystate = 0;

var sand = new Image();
sand.src = "images/sand.png";
sand.onload = function () {
    console.log("Loaded!");
    readystate += 1;
};

var transparentwater = new Image();
transparentwater.src = "images/transparentwater.png";
transparentwater.onload = function () {
    console.log("Loaded!");
    readystate += 1;
};

function draw () {
    if (readystate >= 2) {
        ctx.drawimage(sand, 0, 0, 64, 32);
        ctx.drawimage(transparentwater, 0, 0, 64, 32);
    }
}


var testperframe = setInterval(draw, 10);
```

Any way i can set it up to do this? I know i could probably just use an image editing program to overlay them and then draw the result without needing to overlay during run time, but that would result in a LOT of potential new tiles i would need to draw.

Answer (score 0):

fixed it, turns out i was just having an issue where the sand texture wouldn't actually draw.

The full story was that i had a ctx.drawImage that looked like:

```
ctx.drawImage(tileset, mapdata[x][y][z][dx], mapdata[x][y][z][dy], 64, 32, 0, 0, 64, 32);
```

Where dx and dy are that images posistion on that tile.

What was happening was that dx and dy was pointing to an empty area on the image, so no image was actually drawn under the blue tile.

I've fixed it now and the images now correctly overlay on each other.

Comment: If your question basically involved a typo, you might want to delete it. ;-)